# Is the sample variance for normally distributed data equivalent to the sample variance for data following a bernoulli or binomial distribution?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, means

For normally distributed data, sample variance $s^2$ is:

$$s^2 = \frac1{n-1}\sum (Y_i - \bar Y)^2$$

For a bernoulli distribution, sample variance is:

$$\frac{\hat p \hat q}{n-1}$$

$\hat p = \frac{\sum Y_i}n$, where $Y_i$ is a dummy variable taking on values 0 (e.g., failure) and 1 (e.g., success). Also, $\hat q = 1 - \hat p$.

Are these variances equivalent?

I can pretty easily derive the variances and means from these distributions. However, this doesn't necessarily answer the question.

Alternatively, is there any way to directly derive one variance from the other (if they are in fact equivalent)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some definitions would be a helpful starting point ...

Comment: OP writes:  "For the sample mean $\bar x$, variance is $s^2$:" ... Well no ... $s^2$ is the sample variance (an estimate of the population variance of random variable $Y$, given sample data $Y_i$). It is not the variance of the sample mean.

Comment: You're right. I'll edit my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\hat p \hat q  = \frac{Y_1+\cdots+Y_n}n\cdot\frac{n - (Y_1+\cdots+Y_n)}n
\end{align}

Let $A = \{ i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}: Y_i=1 \}$ and $B = \{ i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}: Y_i=0 \}$. Notice that the number of members of $A$ is $n\bar Y$ and the number of members of $B$ is $n(1-\bar Y)$.   Then we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\bar Y)^2  & = \sum_{i\in A} (1-\bar Y)^2 + \sum_{i\in B} (0-\bar Y)^2 \\[8pt]
& = n\bar Y(1-\bar Y)^2 + n(1-\bar Y)(0-\bar Y)^2 \\[8pt]
& = n\bar Y(1-\bar Y)\Big( (1-\bar Y) + \bar Y \Big) \\[8pt]
& = n\bar Y(1-\bar Y)\cdot 1 = n\hat p\hat q.
\end{align}

Comment: This  made things much clearer for me.  Thank you so much!